# Countdown timer in php using mysql

Tags: php

I want a countdown timer that countdown from certain minutes in a form page. when countdown ends redirect to specific page..

I am trying to create a quiz page that submit when the countdown ends.Please help me to do that... Thankyou...

Comment: You'll need `JavaScript` to do that. PHP cannot submit a form on it's own. MySQL has nothing to do with this as it stands. What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ? What do you really want to do?

Comment: What have you tried? To do this properly you would need a combination of javascript/AJAX and PHP. You would need to store a variable containing the time when the user hits the page, maybe in a session, and then you would need to use AJAX to call a php script every second or few seconds to check how long the user has been on the page.

Comment: Why? Only javascript is needed. No php, nor mysql

Comment: @Gavriel, assuming there's a reason the OP wants a time limit, javascript alone would not work because it is client side and can be cheated.

Comment: He asked about `redirect`, not how to validate whether someone was cheeting

Answer (score 1):

You have to use javascript on the client side to auto submit your form.

The code for the javascript would look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('#quizform').submit();
    },10000);
});
</script>
```

And your form would look like this..

```
<form action="postquiz.php" method="POST" id="quizform">
```

edit: **keep in mind as it is only client side**, ( this can be cheated ) you still need to some how validate the time on the server side. You could use some timestamps for this ( one before he is starting the question and one after submitting, then you could just go for checking if the time is okay )